# bluetooth rfcomm dies after reading first chunk

Tags: linux, bluetooth, serial-port, raspberry-pi, rfcomm

Hello I am trying to read data from a Sensor (Sensaris Sensopod) over bluetooth and I face the below problem:
After lot of tries I managed to connect using:

```
hciconfig hci0 sspmode 1
sdptool add SP
rfcomm connect /dev/rfcomm0 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 1 &
```

and then I use

```
cat /dev/rfcomm0
```

and I get around 30 lines of data and then it simply does nothing. When I close it using ^c and I try the cat again it's showing nothing again (command stays open)

I tried it on Xubuntu and Rasbian (Rpi) and got the same results

Answer (score 0):

RFCOMM is basically an emulation of a serial port. If you just want to read the data from the sensor, you could try binding it, so instead of

```
rfcomm connect /dev/rfcomm0 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 1 &
```

use

```
rfcomm bind 0 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 1
```

this will also create /dev/rfcomm0, and will be bound to the RFCOMM channel number 1 (so make sure your device uses this RFCOMM channel). After that you can connect to it with standard serial utilities like picocom or minicom, like this:

```
picocom /dev/rfcomm0
```

You should be able to read and write to the sensor, just like with other kind of serial port.